# "Parse Issue Expected ']'"

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have looked online but none of the solutions have made a difference.

```
for (int i = 0; i < posts.count; i++) {
    quotesArray addObject: [((NSDictionary *)(posts[i])) objectForKey:@"quote"];
    personArray addObject: [((NSDictionary *)(posts[i])) objectForKey:@"person"];
}
```

The problem is on the second and third lines. What is the problem?

Comment: Where's the square brackets for the calls to `addObject:`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot some brackets when adding objects to your arrays:

```
[quotesArray addObject: [((NSDictionary *)(posts[i])) objectForKey:@"quote"]];
[personArray addObject: [((NSDictionary *)(posts[i])) objectForKey:@"person"]];
```

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I didn't see that >D.